# How to retrieve data from mysql database from php (from for loop)

Tags: php, mysql

I am retrieving some data from mysql database from php. I wrote the following code. But 
**instead of repeating the same code as below, is there any other way to do this?** Because I need to write the same code more than 50 times.
Also I used for loop. But I got the correct answer. But due to for loop answer also repeating as following

- Chapter 1 Outline- 8
- Chapter 1 Presantation Slides- 8
- Chapter 1 Example Activity- 8
- Self Assessment Test 1- 0
- Chapter 1 Outline- 6
- Chapter 1 Presantation Slides- 6
- Chapter 1 Example Activity- 6
- Self Assessment Test 1- 0
- Chapter 1 Outline- 11
- Chapter 1 Presantation Slides- 11
- Chapter 1 Example Activity- 11 Self Assessment Test 1- 0
- Chapter 1 Outline- 0
- Chapter 1 Presantation Slides- 0
- Chapter 1 Example Activity- 0
- Self Assessment Test 1- 49

**but correct output should be**

- Chapter 1 Outline- 8
- Chapter 1 Presentation Slides- 6
- Chapter 1 Example Activity- 11
- Self Assessment Test 1- 49

**May be I am using the for loop brackets wrongly or what is the problem with my code?**
Please help me. I am new to php mysql and learning it from the internet courses. 
(Program is about counting no. of visit to course in Learning management system)

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","", "moodle");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$chap1outr="resource";
$chap1outr1="quiz";


for ($i=81; $i<=116; $i++)
{
    $result1 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT count(*) as counts FROM mdl_log WHERE  userid='2' and module='$chap1outr' AND cmid=$i") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

    while($row1= mysqli_fetch_array( $result1))
    {
        echo "Chapter 1 Outline". "- " . $row1['counts'];
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $result2 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT count(*) as counts1 FROM mdl_log WHERE  userid='2' and module='$chap1outr' AND cmid=$i") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));


    while($row2= mysqli_fetch_array( $result2))

    {
        echo "Chapter 1 Presantation Slides". "- " . $row2['counts1'];
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $result3 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT count(*) as counts2 FROM mdl_log WHERE  userid='2' and module='$chap1outr' AND cmid=$i") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));


    while($row3= mysqli_fetch_array( $result3))

    {
        echo "Chapter 1 Example Activity". "- " . $row3['counts2'];
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $result4 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT count(*) as counts3 FROM mdl_log WHERE  userid='2' and module='$chap1outr1' AND cmid=$i") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));


    while($row4= mysqli_fetch_array( $result4))

    {
        echo "Self Assessment Test 1". "- " . $row4['counts3'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: If this is from an "Internet course" then you should imho follow the course and see what happens. I really can't believe they would let you write the same thing over and over, so you might have missed something.

Comment: Why start your loop counter at 81?

Comment: You want to learn many basics....

Comment: This should be an easy one to do, however, some information is missing. If you are following a tutorial, then you should follow @mgrueter advice, you might have missed something.

Comment: @user2617587 you need to have different conditions to get different count. Your queries have the same conditions. then the count will be same..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","", "moodle");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$chap1outr="resource";
$chap1outr1="quiz";


for ($i=81; $i<=116; $i++)
{
    $result1 = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT count(*) as counts FROM mdl_log WHERE  userid='2' and module='$chap1outr' AND cmid=$i") or die("Error: ".     mysqli_error($con));

    $row1= mysqli_fetch_array( $result1);
    echo "Chapter 1 Outline". "- " . $row1['counts']."<br>";
    echo "Chapter 1 Presantation Slides". "- " . $row1['counts']."<br>";
    echo "Chapter 1 Example Activity". "- " . $row1['counts']."<br>";
    echo "Self Assessment Test 1". "- " . $row1['counts']."<br>";


}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: The `count` will be the same to every field, which, by the original poster question, is not correct.

Comment: The value for `counts` will always be the same, so you'll get a similar result to the one from the original author and not the expected one.